# Google Sheets Script: Using executeQuery() pulling a cell value as a variable

Tags: google-apps-script, jdbc, google-sheets

Is it possible to use a cell value as a criterion in the WHERE clause when using executeQuery() function in a script:

E.g.:

```
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Data');
var summarysheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Summary');
var titles = sheet.getRange('A1:AB1').getValues();

var period = sheet.getRange('C14').getValues();
var results = db.executeQuery('SELECT * FROM My_DB_View WHERE ColumnA = "'+ period +'"');

var numCols = results.getMetaData().getColumnCount();
var resultsArray = [];

function ExampleFunction() {
  db.setMaxRows(2000);
  while (results.next()) {
    var rowArray = [];
    for (var col = 0; col < numCols; col++) {
      rowArray.push(results.getString(col + 1));
    }
    resultsArray.push(rowArray);
  }
  sheet.getRange('A1:AB2000').clearContent();
  sheet.getRange('A1:AB1').setValues(titles);
  sheet.getRange(2, 1, resultsArray.length, numCols).setValues(resultsArray);
  results.close();
  db.close();
}
```

So in the cell D14 I have a value and I want the query to only select rows where column A is matching that value.

Comment: To ensure this question is complete, can you include the code where your variable "db" is defined and clarify what type of database underpins it? (MySQL, Postgres, etc?)

Comment: Well, Does it not work? Also look into parameterized statements.  Embedding unescaped strings like that can cause sql injection attacks.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the problem here is your use of "[getValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getValues())" instead of "[getValue()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getValue())". getValues() returns a two-dimensional array of values, usually it is used when you are getting data from multiple cells, as you are doing with your titles range. While getValue() returns a single value (string, number, boolean, or Date) from a cell.

try:

```
var period = sheet.getRange('C14').getValue();
```

Also, note that your code as it is currently written is vulnerable to [SQL injection attacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). To be completely safe, you should [use prepared statements](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/jdbc#write_to_the_database) instead of executing your query directly.

```
var query = db.prepareStatement('SELECT * FROM My_DB_View WHERE ColumnA = ?');
query.setString(1,period);
var results = query.execute();
```

Comment: Thanks for the info on the prepared statement.
Regarding the suggestion for the getValue() - this has not resolved it. The error is: Exception: Invalid column name '202006'. (line 12, file "Code")

Comment: is 202006 the value in C14?  you might need to wrap the ? in quotes ColumnA = "?", although by my recollection prepared statements do that for you, it might depend on the underlying database.

Comment: Yes the value in C14 is 202006. I've tried with quotes and without but no success. Here are the other variables:
var db = 'winman';
var connector = 'sqlserver';
var address = '';
var username = '';
var password = ''
var connection = Jdbc.getConnection('jdbc:' + connector + '://' + address + ';databaseName=' + db + ';user=' + username + ';password=' + password);
var db = connection.createStatement();

Comment: What is your ```db``` object in the piece of code shown?

Comment: @MateoRandwolf are you asking about my answer, or Ziggy's question? in my answer, I'm assuming it's a JDBC connection instance, as documented here: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/jdbc

Comment: @Ziggy what is your ```db``` object in the piece of the code shown?